# xml parsing data from child tags using sax parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I'm new to android so if I'm asking something stupid so I'm sorry for that. I'm working with the weather parsing in android. I'm using the SAX parser. Now, I am stuck with the content handler.with so many tutorials I got the idea for parsing the data but all of those examples were based on the XML file that does contain the attributes in the tags. for my XML file from where I am retrieving data there no attributes in he tags but the child nodes. now i m stuck here I don't have any idea how can I get the values of the child node.

```
   <data>
   <request>
   <type>City</type>
   <query>Peshawar, Pakistan</query>
   </request>
   <current_condition>
   <observation_time>01:04 PM</observation_time>
   <temp_C>20</temp_C>
   <temp_F>68</temp_F>
   <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
   <weatherIconUrl>
   </weatherIconUrl>
```

now i want to get the data from the "" and the "" and i am really unable to find it please help me. here is my code for the content handler class.

```
public class HandlingXmlStuff extends DefaultHandler {

    XmlDataCollected info=new XmlDataCollected();

    public String getInformation() {        
        return info.dataToString();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(localName.equals("query")) {
            String city=....???;
            info.setCity(city);
        } else if(localName.equals("temp_f")) {
            String t=...???;
            int temp=Integer.parseInt(t);
            info.settemp(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the complete xml file

Comment: http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=peshawar,pakistan&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=eab9f57359164426132301

Comment: Is sax your only choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete parsing solution to extract the values from the [xml data from the url](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=peshawar,pakistan&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=eab9f57359164426132301).

A sample *xml* data from the [provided link](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=peshawar,pakistan&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=eab9f57359164426132301) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <request>
        <type>City</type>
        <query>Peshawar, Pakistan</query>
    </request>
    <current_condition>
        <observation_time>04:31 AM</observation_time>
        <temp_C>7</temp_C>
        <temp_F>45</temp_F>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <windspeedMiles>0</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>0</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirDegree>0</winddirDegree>
        <winddir16Point>N</winddir16Point>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
        <humidity>70</humidity>
        <visibility>4</visibility>
        <pressure>1021</pressure>
        <cloudcover>0</cloudcover>
    </current_condition>
    <weather>
        <date>2013-01-26</date>
        <tempMaxC>22</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>71</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>7</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>45</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>8</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>13</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>NW</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>NW</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>315</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </weather>
    <weather>
        <date>2013-01-27</date>
        <tempMaxC>20</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>68</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>8</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>46</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>7</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>12</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>N</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>N</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>352</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </weather>
    <weather>
        <date>2013-01-28</date>
        <tempMaxC>20</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>68</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>7</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>45</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>9</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>14</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>NW</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>NW</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>316</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </weather>
    <weather>
        <date>2013-01-29</date>
        <tempMaxC>21</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>70</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>8</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>46</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>6</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>9</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>NW</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>NW</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>306</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Sunny]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </weather>
    <weather>
        <date>2013-01-30</date>
        <tempMaxC>19</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>66</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>8</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>47</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>8</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>13</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>WNW</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>WNW</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>289</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>116</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc><![CDATA[Partly Cloudy ]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </weather>
</data>
```

*HandlingXmlStuff.java* :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author visruth
 */
public class HandlingXmlStuff extends DefaultHandler {

    private String key;
    private Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> current_condition = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private List<Map<String, String>> weather = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    private Map<String, String> weatherMap;
    private boolean requestStatus;
    private boolean current_conditionStatus;
    private boolean weatherStatus;

    public Map<String, String> getCurrent_condition() {
        return this.current_condition;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRequest() {        
        return this.request;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getWeather() {        
        return this.weather;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        key = qName;
        if (qName.equals("request")) {

            requestStatus = true;
        } else if (qName.equals("current_condition")) {

            current_conditionStatus = true;
        } else if (qName.equals("weather")) {
            weatherMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            weatherStatus = true;
        }        

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        String value = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
        if (requestStatus) {
            if (!key.trim().equals("request") && !key.trim().isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
                request.put(key, value);
            }            
        } else if (current_conditionStatus) {
            if (!key.trim().equals("current_condition") && !key.trim().isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
                current_condition.put(key, new String(ch, start, length).trim());
            }
        } else if (weatherStatus) {
            if (!key.trim().equals("weather") && !key.trim().isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
                weatherMap.put(key, new String(ch, start, length).trim());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equals("request")) {
            requestStatus = false;
        } else if (qName.equals("current_condition")) {
            current_conditionStatus = false;
        } else if (qName.equals("weather")) {
            weather.add(weatherMap);
            weatherStatus = false;            
        }
    }

    public void parseDocument() {
        //get a factory
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            //get a new instance of parser
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();            
            //parse the file and also register this class for call backs
            sp.parse("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=peshawar,pakistan&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=eab9f57359164426132301", this);
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the values using the following code :

```
HandlingXmlStuff handlingXmlStuf = new HandlingXmlStuff();
handlingXmlStuf.parseDocument();
System.out.println("----values inside request tag-----");
Map<String, String> request = handlingXmlStuf.getRequest();
for (String key : request.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + request.get(key) + ":" + key);
}
System.out.println("----values inside current_condition tag-----");
Map<String, String> current_condition = handlingXmlStuf.getCurrent_condition();
for (String key : current_condition.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + current_condition.get(key) + ":" + key);
}

List<Map<String, String>> weather = handlingXmlStuf.getWeather();
for (Map<String, String> map : weather) {
    System.out.println("\n----each set of weather-----start");
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key) + ":" + key);
    }
    System.out.println("----each set of weather-----end");
}
```

From the above sample *xml* data you will get the below output :

```
----values inside request tag-----
query:Peshawar, Pakistan:query
type:City:type
----values inside current_condition tag-----
cloudcover:0:cloudcover
observation_time:04:31 AM:observation_time
pressure:1021:pressure
temp_C:7:temp_C
visibility:4:visibility
temp_F:45:temp_F
windspeedMiles:0:windspeedMiles
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddirDegree:0:winddirDegree
winddir16Point:N:winddir16Point
weatherIconUrl:http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png:weatherIconUrl
humidity:70:humidity
windspeedKmph:0:windspeedKmph
weatherCode:113:weatherCode
weatherDesc:Sunny:weatherDesc

----each set of weather-----start
windspeedMiles:8:windspeedMiles
winddirection:NW:winddirection
date:2013-01-26:date
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddir16Point:NW:winddir16Point
winddirDegree:315:winddirDegree
weatherIconUrl:http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png:weatherIconUrl
tempMinC:7:tempMinC
windspeedKmph:13:windspeedKmph
tempMaxC:22:tempMaxC
weatherCode:113:weatherCode
tempMaxF:71:tempMaxF
tempMinF:45:tempMinF
weatherDesc:Sunny:weatherDesc
----each set of weather-----end

----each set of weather-----start
windspeedMiles:7:windspeedMiles
winddirection:N:winddirection
date:2013-01-27:date
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddir16Point:N:winddir16Point
winddirDegree:352:winddirDegree
weatherIconUrl:_0001_sunny.png:weatherIconUrl
tempMinC:8:tempMinC
windspeedKmph:12:windspeedKmph
tempMaxC:20:tempMaxC
weatherCode:113:weatherCode
tempMaxF:68:tempMaxF
tempMinF:46:tempMinF
weatherDesc:Sunny:weatherDesc
----each set of weather-----end

----each set of weather-----start
windspeedMiles:9:windspeedMiles
winddirection:NW:winddirection
date:2013-01-28:date
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddir16Point:NW:winddir16Point
winddirDegree:316:winddirDegree
weatherIconUrl:http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png:weatherIconUrl
tempMinC:7:tempMinC
windspeedKmph:14:windspeedKmph
tempMaxC:20:tempMaxC
weatherCode:113:weatherCode
tempMaxF:68:tempMaxF
tempMinF:45:tempMinF
weatherDesc:Sunny:weatherDesc
----each set of weather-----end

----each set of weather-----start
windspeedMiles:6:windspeedMiles
winddirection:NW:winddirection
date:2013-01-29:date
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddir16Point:NW:winddir16Point
winddirDegree:306:winddirDegree
weatherIconUrl:http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png:weatherIconUrl
tempMinC:8:tempMinC
windspeedKmph:9:windspeedKmph
tempMaxC:21:tempMaxC
weatherCode:113:weatherCode
tempMaxF:70:tempMaxF
tempMinF:46:tempMinF
weatherDesc:Sunny:weatherDesc
----each set of weather-----end

----each set of weather-----start
windspeedMiles:8:windspeedMiles
winddirection:WNW:winddirection
date:2013-01-30:date
precipMM:0.0:precipMM
winddir16Point:WNW:winddir16Point
winddirDegree:289:winddirDegree
weatherIconUrl:unny_intervals.png:weatherIconUrl
tempMinC:8:tempMinC
windspeedKmph:13:windspeedKmph
tempMaxC:19:tempMaxC
weatherCode:116:weatherCode
tempMaxF:66:tempMaxF
tempMinF:47:tempMinF
weatherDesc:Partly Cloudy:weatherDesc
----each set of weather-----end
```

The `startElement` invokes when an opening tag is read, the `endElement` invokes when a closing tag is read and the `characters` method invokes each time after `startElement` and `endElement` method invoke.

Comment: o my God.. thank u thank u thank u.. well first i will run this program than on the basis of this i will implement this same code in android. than if there is any problem i will disturb u  again :p

Comment: this is my code for android. it has three classes and and i jux have to parse query tag and temp_f tag.. it takes 2 input that is city an state . than i append the the url with the user input city and state. and then tried to parse the data.. i am trying my best and u helped me alot too. here is the code

Comment: It's my pleasure but you have to vote for these two posts which helped you!!!! I can see now you have the minimum reputation to vote. I advice you to use proper English and only English.

Comment: I could not understand your second comment. what is jux in it?

Comment: @saman I think, first you have to understand how to use the stackoverflow and the rules it says. Why you are posting those codes as different answers???? If you are posing any answers those must be the proper answers for the posted question only. And also you have to post one answer in the single answer post. It's not a good thing you are doing. If you have any doubt in the relevant codes, you can put in the question post. Sorry to say, remember: if you don't follow stackoverflow rules then your account may be blocked/restricted by the reputed members.

Comment: OK i will remove it i didn't knew any thing about the rules. i just posted them to show you my code and if u can help me but its OK i will remove the code no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to get the data from the given xml file.

A sample weather.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <request>
        <type>City</type>
        <query>Peshawar, Pakistan</query>
    </request>
    <current_condition>
        <observation_time>01:04 PM</observation_time>
        <temp_C>20</temp_C>
        <temp_F>68</temp_F>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl> a url </weatherIconUrl>
    </current_condition>
</data>
```

HandlingXmlStuff.java :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author visruth
 */
public class HandlingXmlStuff extends DefaultHandler {

    private boolean typeStatus;
    private boolean queryStatus;
    private boolean observation_timeStatus;
    private boolean temp_CStatus;
    private boolean temp_FStatus;
    private boolean weatherCodeStatus;
    private boolean weatherIconUrlStatus;
    private String type;
    private String query;
    private String observation_time;
    private String temp_C;
    private String temp_F;
    private String weatherCode;
    private String weatherIconUrl;

    public String getObservation_time() {
        return observation_time;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public String getTemp_C() {
        return temp_C;
    }

    public String getTemp_F() {
        return temp_F;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getWeatherCode() {
        return weatherCode;
    }

    public String getWeatherIconUrl() {
        return weatherIconUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equals("type")) {
            typeStatus = true;
        } else {
            typeStatus = false;
        }

        if (qName.equals("query")) {
            queryStatus = true;
        } else {
            queryStatus = false;
        }

        if (qName.equals("observation_time")) {
            observation_timeStatus = true;
        } else {
            observation_timeStatus = false;
        }
        if (qName.equals("temp_C")) {
            temp_CStatus = true;
        } else {
            temp_CStatus = false;
        }

        if (qName.equals("temp_F")) {
            temp_FStatus = true;
        } else {
            temp_FStatus = false;
        }

        if (qName.equals("weatherCode")) {
            weatherCodeStatus = true;
        } else {
            weatherCodeStatus = false;
        }
        if (qName.equals("weatherIconUrl")) {
            weatherIconUrlStatus = true;
        } else {
            weatherIconUrlStatus = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (typeStatus) {
            this.type = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            typeStatus = false;
        }

        if (queryStatus) {
            this.query = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            queryStatus = false;
        }
        if (observation_timeStatus) {
            this.observation_time = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            observation_timeStatus = false;
        }
        if (temp_CStatus) {
            this.temp_C = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            temp_CStatus = false;
        }
        if (temp_FStatus) {
            this.temp_F = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            temp_FStatus = false;
        }
        if (weatherCodeStatus) {
            this.weatherCode = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            weatherCodeStatus = false;
        }
        if (weatherIconUrlStatus) {
            this.weatherIconUrl = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
            weatherIconUrlStatus = false;
        }

    }

    public void parseDocument() {
        //get a factory
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            //get a new instance of parser
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            //parse the file and also register this class for call backs
            sp.parse(TestCase.class.getResource("wheather.xml").getPath(), this);
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the data using the following code :

```
HandlingXmlStuff handlingXmlStuf = new HandlingXmlStuff();
handlingXmlStuf.parseDocument();
System.out.println("type:" + handlingXmlStuf.getType() + ":type");
System.out.println("observation_time:" + handlingXmlStuf.getObservation_time() + ":observation_time");
System.out.println("temp_C:" + handlingXmlStuf.getTemp_C() + ":temp_C");
System.out.println("temp_F:" + handlingXmlStuf.getTemp_F() + ":temp_F");
System.out.println("weatherCode:" + handlingXmlStuf.getWeatherCode() + ":weatherCode");
System.out.println("weatherIconUrl:" + handlingXmlStuf.getWeatherIconUrl() + ":weatherIconUrl");
```

Comment: thank u so much well u helped me a lot. i don't want to ask an other question... in the second code u pasted whats weather.xml. i arranged the code for my project but it still don't work .. would u help me if i paste all my code and the link i m parsing data from?

Comment: @saman why not you vote for the post if you find it helpful???. weather.xml is a file containing the xml data which you have included in your post. I have posted the complete answer as a separate answer.

Comment: the code u pasted above do work with java but not with android. i have send you a message on Facebook with my project file if u do have some understanding with android please help me in this regard i request. @visruth

Comment: @saman 
I haven't received any message.You can contact me using the contact us form in [http://visruthcv.appspot.com/](http://visruthcv.appspot.com). Fill the form correctly and include all your doubts in the message field in the form. You will get a confirmation reply after posting, then you can reply your project code to that mail.
  
Well, did you give the needful permissions (like internet) in your android manifest file? if not give it.

Comment: how do i parse the image form the same link. it shows me the links besides showing image. can u tel me?

Comment: @saman
You can use classes like  BitMap, BufferedImage etc...
For example :
**URL url=new URL("http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png");
         URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
         InputStream inputStream = openConnection.getInputStream();
         BufferedImage imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(inputStream); **

 if you don't understand put it as an another question with the reference of this post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566209/   how-to-parse-the-image-from-url-sax-parsing here is the link of the question i didn't knew how to add new question with refrence to this one.