# how to parse the image from url SAX parsing

Tags: java, xml, image, saxparser

how do i parse the image form the link inside the xml file url.when i parse the data it shows me the link  besides showing image. here is the link of image http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png

and the link i an parsing data from

http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=peshawar,pakistan&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=eab9f57359164426132301

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The URL of the imagine is in the weatherIconUrl node. So it's easy to extract it when you parse it with Sax. Is it what you are trying to do? Or are you trying to extract the picture name from the URL?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do with the image url? Add needful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to make a buffered image from the url.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png");
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new FileOutputStream("/home/visruth/OutputImage.png"));// A file named OutputImage.png will be created in the location /home/visruth/
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```